# DDD - Comunicação entre Camadas

Tags: ddd

Lendo um documento sobre DDD fiquei com dúvida sobre o seguinte parágrafo, na parte grifada.

"...as camadas (interface, Aplicação, Domínio e infraestrutura) devem estar desassociadas uma da outra se comunicando sempre através de interfaces
**e a camada inferior nunca disparar operações na camada superior**..."

Como se aplicaria esta situação no caso de eventos assincronos onde, por exemplo, a camada de infraestrura deve informar a camada de aplicação/interface que algum processo foi concluido, ou as próprias camadas de dominio/aplicação, informando para a camada de interface do mesmo?

Sendo um evento async (Node por exemplo) desconectado, o resultado do callback esta dentro da camada executora do mesmo e não na camada anterior. Concordo que se o processo for síncrono ele segue o caminho de retorno, mas no async ele (quase sempre) é disparado dentro do contexto de sua execução.

Ficou clara a dúvida? Agradeço qualquer link de documento e/ou código que demonstre este conceito.